# How to check if the current page's parent is one of 2 different ID's

Tags: conditional-tags, child-pages

I'm using this little snippet right now to check if the current page is the child of a particular page;

```
$studies_parent = 5860;
if ($studies_parent == $post->post_parent) {
```

Which is working fine, although now I need to check if the current page is a child of one of 2 different ID's and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Basically I need to check if the current page's parent is either 5860 or 1047. Any ideas how I'd do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add following function into your `functions.php` file:

```
function is_child_of() { 
    global $post; 
    return is_page() && in_array( $post->post_parent, func_get_args() );
}
```

And use it in your template like this:

```
if ( is_child_of( 5860, 1047 ) ) {
    // is child of 5860 or 1047
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, it just kills the page after I try and execute the function

Comment: looks like you have added it incorrectly because the snippet doesn't contain any errors or bugs. what error do you see?

Comment: No error, the page just stops right where I've added the snippet